# iOS Application crashing unexpectedly

Tags: ios, uikit, calayer

My application crashing unexpectedly. In my app I am presenting a modal view controller and sometime it get crash on pressing close button to dismiss controller.

I am attaching crashlog for the same. Unable to detect the reason after viewing log.

Thanks [image: Crash log]
[image: Crash log 2]

Comment: Please can you include what is appearing in the logs so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Can you check whether you are dismissing the viewcontroller from main thread itself. If NO, please dismiss the viewcontroller in main thread